Confused about Linux multicast
I am struggling with two executables that I have built, which should communicate over multicast. In my current setup they should communicate over the loopback device.
For this I have executed two commands before starting anything:

ifconfig lo multicast
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo

My sending application does roughly this, in this order:

getaddrinfo
socket
setsockopt(IP_MULTICAST_LOOP)
connect

My listening application does roughly this, in this order:

getaddrinfo
socket
connect
setsockopt(IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP)

When the two programs run, the wlan0 interface is also up besides lo.
My listening application receives nothing when I have the route towards 224.0.0.0 enabled, but tcpdump does . When I remove that route and restart the listening application everything works fine.
I wonder what steps I can take to debug this? It appears as if my sending application is always sending over the wlan0 interface.

bind the sockets to the localhost IP address first.

"My sending application does roughly this" is of no interest whatsoever. What is required is precisely what it does, as expressed in source code. And specifically it is of no interest whatsoever what you think it does. It doesn't do that, otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question.

Why connect and not listen on the server?

listen() is specifically for TCP connections, and multicast happens via UDP.

Note that connect() is often not a good idea for multicast, since doing a connect() on a UDP socket installs a receive-filter on the socket such that it will only receive UDP packets whose source-IP-address field exactly match the IP address specified in the connect() call, and multicast packets typically have the unicast IP address of the sender as their source-IP address, not the IP address of the multicast group.  I would suggest commenting out the connect() calls, at least for now, and using sendto() and recvfrom() instead.

Changing the code to use send and recv fixed the issue for me.
